# Verify bash scripts with "bash -n <name>" before installing, how do I do that in a CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: bash, cmake, verification

I have the following in my `CMakeLists.txt` file to install a bash script:

```
install(
    PROGRAMS
        backup-wordpress

    DESTINATION
        bin
)
```

That works as expected, no issue here.

However, before being able to install that script, I'd like to run:

```
bash -n backup-wordpress
```

to generally make sure it will run and not just fail because of some basic syntax error.

How do I run that `bash -n ...` command against a file which just gets installed by the cmake install command and make sure that command happens every time the script is modified?

I know of `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()`, but those are expected to create an intermediate file. I'm not too sure how it would apply to my case.

Comment: Using `install(CODE)` or `install(SCRIPT)` you could specify additional steps for installation. If your script is generated by some custom command, then you could add additional COMMAND for verify the script.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Interesting. The [`SCRIPT` and `CODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic) commands do not even have to do the installation, they just need to appear before the `install(PROGRAMS ...)` I already have because [_" Install rules specified by calls to the `install()` command within a source directory are executed in order during installation."_](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#introduction).